# configure command in cygwin64 return error gcc not found

Tags: python, gcc, cygwin

i want run ./configure && make command in cygwin but it return error below

```
$ ./configure && make
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

i dont know how install gcc for windows

i setup cygwin full packages

also tried this command

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/c/cygwin64/bin
```

before run make command

Comment: what is the output of  `cygcheck -c gcc-core` ? Why python `tag` ?

Comment: its for install libdnet library in python 
 @matzeri

Comment: you missed to answer my first question. You are also missing to provide all info to understand and replicate your problem Which `python` are you using ? Which version of `libdnet` are you trying to install and how ?